# Does this example Tcl code really function similar to how JS promises handle asynchronous events?

Tags: asynchronous, tcl, coroutine

I've been experimenting with using Tcl as a local server for a desktop application using a browser as the GUI, and using web sockets. Thus far the web sockets are working and I can send a request from the browser to Tcl, retrieve data from a SQLite database, and pass it back to the browser. And it's not difficult to set up a promise-like process in JS to "wait" for Tcl to respond in a non-blocking manner. Also, I've sent a request id on each message to Tcl such that when it responds JS knows which promise to resolve/reject.

My question concerns working in the other direction; that is, initiating a message from Tcl and waiting for the browser to respond and in a non-blocking manner.

In the code below I'm using a coroutine to store the callback procedure and any relevant arguments at the time the request is sent from Tcl to the browser; and then using the id to have the readable event handler call the correct coroutine and pass it the response. Then the coroutine calls the original callback with its arguments and the response received from the browser.

I tried to simulate a delay in sending two messages through a pipe at different times to see if this would work similar to the asynchronous manner of JS. It appears to provide similar results but, of course, is a very simple example.

Would you please tell me if this is the correct approach to take to accomplish this, and tell me of better ones? Thank you for considering my question.

Would you please also tell me why each coro$id doesn't require a separate coSend$id procedure? It doesn't matter if both messages are sent at the same ms, each calls the correct call back with the correct arguments and response. Thanks.

```
proc coSend {callBack args} {
 set response [yield]
 $callBack $response $args
}

proc redo {x} {
  if {$x < 11} {
    chan puts stdout "x: $x => [expr {$x*100}]ms gone by."
    incr x
    after 100 redo $x
  } else {
    set ::forever 1
  }
}

proc ReadLine {chan} {
  if {[catch {chan gets $chan line} len]} {
      chan puts stdout "Error in chan $chan"
      return
  }
  set response [string trim [lassign [split $line] id]]
  coro$id $response
}

proc SendMessage {callBack args msg delay} {
  coroutine coro[set id [GetMsgID]] coSend $callBack $args
  after $delay MimicResponse "$id {$msg}"
}

proc MimicResponse {args} {
  chan puts $::wchan $args
}

proc GetMsgID {} {
  return [incr ::msg_id]
}

proc CallBack_1 {response args} {
  chan puts stdout "$args $response"
}

proc CallBack_2 {response args} {
  chan puts stdout "$args $response"
}

lassign [chan pipe] rchan wchan
chan configure $rchan -buffering line -blocking 1 -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf
chan configure $wchan -buffering line -blocking 1 -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf
chan event $rchan readable [list ReadLine $rchan]

set msg_id 0
redo 1
SendMessage CallBack_1 {arg11 arg12} "This is the response to the first message that should return second." 700
SendMessage CallBack_2 {arg21 arg22 arg23} "This is the response to the second message that should return first." 300

set forever 0
vwait forever

# Results are:
# x: 1 => 100ms gone by.
# x: 2 => 200ms gone by.
# x: 3 => 300ms gone by.
# {{arg21 arg22 arg23}} \{This is the response to the second message that should return first.\}
# x: 4 => 400ms gone by.
# x: 5 => 500ms gone by.
# x: 6 => 600ms gone by.
# x: 7 => 700ms gone by.
# {{arg11 arg12}} \{This is the response to the first message that should return second.\}
# x: 8 => 800ms gone by.
# x: 9 => 900ms gone by.
# x: 10 => 1000ms gone by.
`
```

Comment: Tcl's `after` works exactly the same as `setTimeout` in js - it is fully asynchronous. Tcl has one advantage that js does not. It has an `update` command which allows you to enter the event loop on demand (for example, if you have a long synchronous for or while loop you can call `update` every X iterations to force the event loop to run - can't do that in js). I used to say Tcl was the only language that is aware of **time** because you can schedule functions to be called in the order you want - not just sequentially...

Comment: ... Javascript is the second language I discovered to have this awareness of time. Nowdays we call this intrinsic ability to play with time "asynchronous" (It has always been called asynchronous at the C/assembly level but Tcl's documentation almost never use that word - instead programmers just kind of naturally understood how asynchronous code worked with the `-command` option. Which is why I found how people react to and misunderstand javascript's asynchronous nature very strange)

Comment: So just like in js, Tcl itself cannot create asynchronousness (js also cannot really create asynchronousness - functions that are asynchronous are asynchronous and functions that are not are not). Weather or not you can make use of the asynchronous nature depends on if your database functions are asynchronous - if they accept a callback then they are probably async. If they force you to wait for a return value then they are certainly blocking the event loop.

Comment: @slebetman Thank you for all the information and insight. I appreciate it.

Comment: @slebetman In regards to your comment about `update` to force the event loop to run in Tcl and not being able to do the same in JS, I just recalled messing around with making a progress bar in JS that updated the bar every nth iterations of a loop and I had to use `            setTimeout( updateDOM, 0 )` or the bar (DOM) would not update until the loop completed. Is that a form of a hack to get JS to do something it wasn't really made to do? Thanks.

Comment: No. setTimeout does not enter the event loop. It just schedules your `updateDOM` function to run in the next round of the event loop. I'm talking about doing something like `setTimeout(updateDOM,0); while (1) { x++; if (x%100==0) update()}`. In js that code will never run `updateDOM` because of the infinite `while` loop. But if js had the `update` function like Tcl then after 100 rounds of the infinite while loop that `setTimeout` will be processed and `updateDOM` will be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tcl, coroutines are really little stacks; you can `yield` anywhere in the call hierarchy, and do not need to track what's going on. (In some other languages, this would make them "colorless"; you don't need the async/await ceremony to call them.) The things that need to be aware of how they've been called can use `info coroutine` to discover if they're running in a coroutine context or not.

The disadvantage of this is that coroutines are comparatively expensive, as they have a (Tcl) stack (but no C stack; Tcl avoids loading that up, and it was work to do that that stack reduction spun out both `coroutine` and `tailcall`) so you're best associating one of those per significant ongoing operation. An example would be having one for each connection made to a server when there's a non-trivial protocol present, at least until such time as the effort is transferred to another worker thread.

If you're doing much with I/O and coroutines, the [coroutine package in Tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/coroutine/tcllib_coroutine.md) is recommended for handling the basics of making apparently synchronous code be actually asynchronous.

Comment: The js equivalent of coroutine are generators. Those weird functions that are marked with `*` like `function* myCoroutine () {/*...*/}`. Notice that generally js programmers don't use coroutines/generators to handle async behavior with the major exception of the Koa framework. Generally js programmers use coroutines to generate dynamic/infinite lists because in js generators are iterable with `for .. of`